# Firebase rules not applying to subcollection documents

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Here are my rules

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /Users/{id}{
        allow read : if (request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid);
      allow write : if false;
    }
    
   
    match /Class/{id}{
        allow read : if (request.auth.uid == resource.data.instructor.uid || (request.auth.uid == resource.data.admin.uid));
     
      allow write : if false;
    }
   
    match /Class/{id}/Topics/{doc} {
             allow read:
       if request.auth.uid == resource.data.topicOwnerUID || request.auth.uid == resource.data.adminUID
        allow write: if false;
        }
    
  }
}
```

Everything is fine except trying to pull all the topics from Class/docs/Topics/docs. I use getDocuments and try to get all documents using limit(50), I only have 1 topic now, but I also tried making limit to 1 and still don't work.. In each of the Topics docs, there is an adminUID and a topicOwnerUID field. When the owner tries to pull all documents I am getting an error: "Error: Missing or insufficient permissions.". I checked and all the required fields are there and this should allow.

Edit: seems like if i remove .limit and just get a single doc with a specific docID it works. But this isn't what I want :/. Maybe I will have to make the subcollection into its own collection.

Edit2: doesn't work even if it is not a subcollection. completely lost rn. Looks like the only way is to get each doc individually but this ruins lazyLoading. Firebase is lagging behind. will be switching to another db.

Answer (score 1):

Security rules do not mean anything without the matching queries - remember that Security Rules ARE NOT FILTERS - they will NOT "just give you the records that are allowed" - you MUST use queries to match your rules.  If your query *could* return a document that isn't allowed by the rules, then the ENTIRE query is disallowed.

I can tell you from EXTENSIVE use that Firebase/Firestore do not lag behind in any way, and I use complex queries continuously.

Comment: I adding queries in my frontend before getDocuments and it still don't work. If I must get rid of security rules and allow read to all wouldn't that be a huge security risk?

Comment: I solved it. Would love it if they added an OR operator to compare strings.

Comment: The closest to an OR operation is the (very) recently added "in" operator, which allows you to check is the field is any of the entries IN an array.  10 elements max.  Beyond that, it takes multiple queries.